# passing data to route's component beforeEnter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have the following VueRouter route

```js
{
  path: '/playlists/:id',
  name: 'videos',
  component: Video,
  props: {
    videos: [],
  },
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    Vue.axios
      .get('/playlistitems?playlistId='.concat(to.params.id))
      .then((response) => {
        to.params.videos = response.data
        next((vm) => {
          console.log(vm)
          vm.videos = response.data
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('error', err))
  },
}
```

When the route is entered into everything executes as expected but I'm not sure how to pass the `response.data` to the route's component `Videos`

Question 1

- Can you set the Vue component's **props** property from the Router?

Question 2

- The route is a dynamic route. If the route and component is already loaded and the dynamic parameter changes....does `beforeEnter` still fire? If not where should I put my data fetching logic? Do I `watch` for route changes inside the **Vue component**?

Answer (score 2):

1)

This might not be the most elegant approach, but here's a way to achieve that:

```js
let videos = [];

export default new Router({ ... });

{
      path: '/playlists/:id',
      name: 'videos',
      component: Video,
      props: route => ({ videos }),
      beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
        Vue.axios.get('/playlistitems?playlistId='.concat(to.params.id))
          .then((response) => {
            // Now the data will be available when the props will be initialized
            videos = response.data
            next()
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log('error', err))
      }
    }
```

```js
// Videos.vue

props: {
    videos: Array
  },
```

2)
IMHO, it would be easier if you could encapsulate the logic in the component. 
What do I mean by that is that you could fetch your data in the `created` hook and set it to a variable that you defined in your `data` function.

```js
 data() {
    return {
      videos: []
    }
  },

  created () {
    Vue.axios.get('/playlistitems?playlistId='.concat(this.$route.params.id))
    .then((response) => {
      this.videos = response.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('error', err))
  },
```

**Another approach**, which may be suitable or not, depending on what you're working on, would be to have a parent component that fetches multiple playlists which could be stored in vuex.
Thus, you would have another component that handles `playlists/:id`.
Within this last mentioned component, in your `created` hook, you would have something like this:

```js
created () {
    this.$store.commit('playlist/SET_CURRENT_PLAYLIST_ID', this.$route.params.id);
    this.videos = this.$store.getters['playlits/getVideosByPlaylistId'];
  },
```