# Pass data with beforeEnter to route components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

How would I go about having a function called with `beforeEnter` pass data to the corresponding route component(s)?

The purpose of beforeEnter in this case is to confirm that a valid bearer token is present as a cookie.

Currently, I have `beforeEnter` hitting aws api gateway on `/verify/auth`, and then the component loads and makes a call to dynamodb on `/list/repos`. The thing is, both routes are protected with a builtin AWS api gatewayV2 JWT authorizer, so it's kind of pointless to hit `/verify/auth`.

What I would like is to make `beforeEnter` hit `/list/repos`, leverage the built in JWT authorizer, and load the next page with the data obtained from the api call. If the user isn't properly authenticated, `beforeEnter` won't send the user to the route.

So:

- api call -> load page

rather than

- api call -> load page -> api call

Here's my code. I had a look at a similar question here, but wasn't able to figure it out. [passing data to route's component beforeEnter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725120/passing-data-to-routes-component-beforeenter)

**index.js**

```
let repositories = [];

async function listRepositories(to, from, next) {
  var isAuthenticated = false;
  console.log("testing listRepositories...");
  if (Vue.$cookies.get("Authorization")) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        process.env.VUE_APP_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT + "/list/repos",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: '{"repo_owner": "sean"}',
          headers: {
            Authorization: Vue.$cookies.get("Authorization")
          }
        }
      );
      repositories = await response.json();
      console.log(repositories);
      if (repositories.message != "Unauthorized") {
        isAuthenticated = true;
        // return {
        //   repositories
        // };
        next();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    console.log("error not authenticated");
    to("/");
  }
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    component: () => import("../views/Login.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/repos",
    name: "Repos",
    // beforeEnter: isAuthenticated,
    beforeEnter: listRepositories,
    props: repositories => {
      {
        repositories;
      }
    },
    component: () => import("../views/Repos.vue")
  }
];
```

**./views/Repos.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="small-container">
    <repo-table
      :repositories="repositories"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RepoTable from "@/components/RepoTable.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    RepoTable
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: {
    repositories: {
      type: Array
    }
  }
</script>
```

**./components/RepoTable.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="repository-table">
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left">Repository</th>
        // omitted for brevity
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(repo, index) in repositories" :key="repo.repo_name">
          <td>
            <b>{{ repo.repo_name }}</b>
            // omitted for brevity
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "repository-table",
  data() {
    return {
      // repositories: []
    };
  },
  props: {
    repositories: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
```

Comment: The `to` call should be `next`, and there are other issues.  When the authentication was valid did the console show what you expected?

Comment: `next()` is working fine, it hits my backend and takes me to `/repos` as expected, but it isn't able to pass the data along through to `/repos`. The data is definitely there, just not passed on. Admittedly, `to()` isn't working properly and I'm sure there are other issues, but I'm not too concerned about that one as I haven't gotten there yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using route params with `beforeEnter`

You can pass data from `beforeEnter` using route params.  When the value of `props` is `true`, route params will be converted to props:

```
props: true
```

Now you just need a param called `repositories` and it will be passed as a prop to the destination.  In your `beforeEnter`, when the user is authenticated you can add that param:

```
if (repositories.message != "Unauthorized") {
  isAuthenticated = true;
  to.params.repositories = repositories;  // ✅ Adding the data to the param
  next();
}
```

Other fixes:

- Change `to('/')` to `next('/')`
- Add a `next` in every logic path, for example when there is an error and when neither `if` condition is met.
- Each time you call `next` call it with `return` like `return next`

Another option:

You could also achieve this using the [`beforeRouteEnter`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) in-component guard.