# Flickering content when trying to show non-authenticated and authenticated content on the same page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

(Nuxt project)
I am stuck finding a solution related to show non-authenticated and authenticated content on the same page.

I have two possible solutions in my mind but they have some caveats.

The first one, decides on the `mounted` method if the user can see the authenticated content but I couldn't solve the flickering content issue, this is the demo for that approach:
https://60f08a8293123d00e57c14e8--happy-minsky-1268c6.netlify.app/
Click the login button and reload the page, you will see the flickering content

My second approach, it is using the `null` to avoid both, the non-authenticated and authenticated content until the app reaches the `mounted` method, the problem with this solution is it is not search engine friendly because there is no static content generation, please compare this two links:

**Generated from this solution:** https://gist.github.com/ltroya-as/fbbdce2b3dc30063e9c4ec7e93e3aba1#file-index-generated-file-html-L522

**Expected:** https://gist.github.com/ltroya-as/d37e3d0a89efebbfd66c2daf7700f50d#file-expected-generated-file-html-L523

Is there a way to make the second solution more search engine friendly? I am worried that the second solution affects search engine results.

Repository with instructions:
https://github.com/ltroya-as/nuxt-rehydratation-example

--- Update

My project is configured in full static mode

Comment: What are you trying to SEO here? `No authenticated content`? If you want a smoother effect, maybe try to look for a transition or any other CSS solution: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components Even tho, you can totally define what should be sent ahead of time and generate it on the server (`target: server`) directly. Because rehydration will by default cause a "flicker" indeed.

Comment: Can you please answer to my previous comment please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue is a client side framework. All HTML is generated by JS inside the browser. This means that typical Vue app is just very simple HTMl file with almost no HTML and some CSS and Javascript  tags...

This is problem for SEO because most crawlers (Google, FB, Twitter) do not execute JS and just scan the HTML returned from server...

To solve this, frameworks as Nuxt was created. They solve the problem by executing Vue app on the server and rendering the HTML on the server - either at request time (Nuxt classic - new HTML is generated each time the request comes - needs Node server) or at build time (Nuxt generate - HTML is generated to a file at build time and same HTML is returned for each request)

In all cases, HTML returned by the server is different but everything else is same. **It is still a Vue app**, which is executed on the client and once it is started (and that takes some time - so user sees only the content send by the server in the meantime), it overrides any HTML returned from the server...

This is why you see the "flickering" and I'm afraid there is no easy solution to this problem when your site if fully statically generated.

1. Solution with using `null` - result is clear, no content -> no SEO. There is no way around it...
2. If your target is SEO, I guess rendering content for authenticated clients by default makes no sense as that would reveal such content to Google (or other crawler) and it's users so why to hide it behind authentication in the first place...
3. Only option left is to generate content for non authenticated users and live with the flickering for users already logged-in

I think if you know about the problem, you can minimize it by the design - for example do not mix both auth/non-auth content on the single page for example. But for your simple and "not from real life" example it has no solution

Comment: Not sure if OP is still answering, hence we cannot help him without further details. :(

Comment: A real case scenario in the company is that they have `Megafactories` page, on that page they show `Megafactories` related information such as what they are, importance, how the company is related to this, and so on (marketing things)

Comment: Looking more in-depth about the problem and possible solutions, I found this article https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme. What do you guys think about it?

Comment: @LTroya Read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/9kqs88/is_serverside_rendering_still_necessary_for_seo/). Google isn't the only search engine. Plus indexing of JS heavy page (which Vue SPA is) means Google needs much more computation resources to do that. I remember video from some conference where the lector explained that this can cause long periods of time your site is not indexed or only partially indexed....

Comment: Also [this](https://www.onely.com/blog/ultimate-guide-javascript-seo/#chapter-2) is very good resource on SEO of JS heavy sites...

Comment: Thanks for all the articles! The company only cares for chrome at the moment and we use nuxt to increase the performance of the app. I think we are good for the moment, I will look for more info and ways to improve that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use beforeEach (navigation guards) - this one should do the trick. You can use it to check if the user is logged in or not there, https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

something like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I think that this answer it will help you [Pass data with beforeEnter to route components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865585/pass-data-with-beforeenter-to-route-components)

Comment: The equivalent of that on nuxt is middleware, isn't it?

Comment: I tried to use middleware but it doesn't work. You can see the last commit here https://github.com/ltroya-as/nuxt-rehydratation-example/tree/using-middleware

Comment: A middleware and router guard is not exactly the thing @LTroya.

Comment: In nuxt context, what will be the equivalent for that? @kissu

Comment: For `beforeEnter`? There is not equivalent needed since you can use it as a component guard: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards Middleware is specific to Nuxt, and works well too @LTroya

Comment: Can you create an example using Nuxt? You can use my example as a base, please @kissu

Comment: @LTroya I'm still not sure what you're expecting since you did not answered my comments under your question.

Comment: I am not sure how to use `beforeEnter` on Nuxt since all the routes are dynamically generated @kissu